# Firebase/Flutter: Compiler reads map<String, dynamic> as map<dynamic, dynamic> can't solve it :/

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating authentication service with Firebase and i have UserModel to work with users data, i have a class with a function:

```
class UserModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  late String uid;
  late String username;
  late String email;
  late String password;
  late String type;

  UserModel.empty();

  UserModel(
      String uid, String username, String email, String password, String type) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.type = type;
     }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(UserModel user) {
    var data = Map<String, dynamic>();

    data["uid"] = user.uid;
    data["nickname"] = user.username;
    data["email"] = user.email;
    data["password"] = user.password;
    data["type"] = user.type;

    return data;
  }
}
```

And a class where i have functions to authenticate:

```
class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
  UserModel userModel = UserModel.empty();
  final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  AuthenticationService(this._firebaseAuth);

  Stream<User?> get authStateChanges => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

  Future<void> addUserToDB(
      {required String uid,
      required String username,
      required String email,
      required String password,
      required String type}) async {
    userModel = UserModel(uid, username, email, password, type);
    var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    await userRef.doc(uid).set(userModel.toMap(userModel));
  }
}
```

There i have an error:

> The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Temporary im doing it without using `UserModel`, but i really want to fix it.

Comment: try changing return type of toMap method into `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case was i missspelled an import and it was reading my old `UserModel` :D

UserModel had to be `map<String,dynamic>` cuz `set` function told that it can't work with `map<dynamic,dynamic>`.

So the code above is fine and works for me.

Thanks for help!